# How to run different timer inside a timer without pausing the GUI?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a class SendCountingInfo() and it will send a message to server every 5 minutes. The code inside this class are:

```
public void StartSendCountingInfo()
{
      DoStartSendCountingInfo(300000);
}

private void DoStartSendCountingInfo(int iMiSecs)
{
      _pingTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(iMiSecs);
      _pingTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(pingTimer_Elapsed);
      _pingTimer.Start();
}

void pingTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    PingRemoteHost();
}
```

When I try to call it in the Windows Form class, it didn't work.
But, when I remove the timer and call PingRemoteHost() directly, it works. However, the form didn't load properly. It shows blank screen but the method PingRemoteHost() work.

Here is the code inside the windows form:

```
private void Layout_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     tSystemChecker = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
     tSystemChecker.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(tSystemChecker_Elapsed);
     tSystemChecker.Start();

     this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}

void tSystemChecker_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    UIThreadWork(this, delegate
    {
        try
        {
             SuspendLayout();
             DoCheckHardwareStatus();
             DoCheckLanguage();

             SendCountingInfo sci = new SendCountingInfo();
             sci.StartSendCountingInfo();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exp.Source);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exp.StackTrace);
        }

        ResumeLayout(true);
   });
}
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread and see if the problem persist

```
using System.Threading;
//Put this where you want to start the first timer
Thread thread = new Thread(dowork =>
{
    public void StartSendCountingInfo();
}
```

If you are updating the GUI use for your controls

```
guicontrol.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() 
{ 
    guicontrol.Text = "aa";
    //etc
});
```